# Why does angular-cache ignore capacity configuration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, caching

I use [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) with localStorage to save articles locally in html5. The [documentation states](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#capacity) that there is an option called "capacity":

> **capacity**
>
> Maximum number of items a cache can hold. Adding more items
>   than the capacity will cause the cache to operate like an LRU cache,
>   removing the least recently used items to stay under capacity.
>   Default: Number.MAX_VALUE.

Since I only want to store a max of 20 articles, I configure like this:

```
CacheFactory('articleCache', {
  storagePrefix : 'my.news.',
  capacity : 20,
  storageMode: 'localStorage'
});
```

And when I want to get data, I simply do:

```
$http.get(url, {cache: CacheFactory.get('articleCache')});
```

After using my app for a while I suddenly noticed that it stopped working because localStorage limit quota was reached. When I printed `console.log(localStorage)`, I saw that there were a lot more than just 20 articles stored to localStorage. So, for some reason angular-cache does not delete the oldest items although the documentation promised the opposite.

So, did I do something wrong or is there a bug in angular-cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a bug in angular-cache which got now fixed in version 4.4.3, see https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache/issues/210

After installing the update my app runs as expected.